# How can you associate your registered trademark to your website when that specific term is searched on Google or other Web Crawlers?

Tags: wordpress, seo, web-crawler, google-search, google-search-console

On Bing & Yahoo our link is showing up on the first page, but I am having issues with it showing up on google search. Here are additional details:

- The term is the title of the wordpress blog & it has been officially registered with the USPTO.
- The site has been active since Jan 17,2016, so far we have 8 posts on it and we want to continue to post fun/relevant posts on the blog.
- Thought a trademark association would be in Google Webmaster Tools, but it isn't there.
- I looked at Ad Words and saw that it isn't a commonly searched term at all, so figured our blog would come up on the first page.
- Been trying different SEO plugins & methods to improve the search for the term, but nothing seems to be working.

This seems to be a very odd issue. I been looking everywhere to figure this one out, but haven't found anything, and I am not sure who to turn to for help. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

SEO is a tricky one,

but it works like this

1. Meta Description is number one (paste your url I can have a look at the code)
2. Meta Title (page Title)
3. Length the domain has been online
4. Number of crosslinks
5. Sitemap submission to google (then fetch url )
6. Make sure your robot.txt is not denying search engines
7. Make sure your website has content.

http://swiftmedia.ca/marketing.php